Скрипт для умножения множества чисел на 1.4
У меня есть конфиг, в котором есть данные.
Вот маленькая часть:
TLISP5
{
    key = 0 352
    key = 1 123
}

TLTWR5 = 35.3
TLCOST5 = 1.85
TLTECH5 = heavierRocketry
TLTHROTTLE5 = 0.15
TLISP6
{
    key = 0 357
    key = 1 125
}

TLTWR6 = 36.5
TLCOST6 = 1.95
TLTECH6 = veryHeavyRocketry
TLTHROTTLE6 = 0.1

В _ISP есть key = x n.
Помогите сделать скрипт, чтобы n умножалось на 1.4.
То есть было так:
TLISP5
{
    key = 0 352
    key = 1 123
}

А стало:
TLISP5
{
    key = 0 528
    key = 1 185
}

Скрипт должен перезаписывать эти числа, и надо сделать целый файл.

Что-то здесь не так... 352*1,4 = 492,8. А не 528

Наверное, можно сделать так:
import re

def mul_1_4(match):
    s = match.group()
    return str(round(int(s) * 1.4))

file = open('name', 'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()

file = open('name1', 'w')
file.write(re.sub(r'\d+', mul_1_4, text)))
file.close()


выдает
   TLISP5.6
   {
    key = 0.0 475.99999999999994
    key = 1.4 285.59999999999997
   }
   TLTWR5.6 = 89.6
   TLCOST5.6 = 1.4.105.0
   TLTECH5.6 = heavyRocketry
   TLTHROTTLE5.6 = 0.0.11.2


Значит, надо округлять в ближайшую сторону - return str(round(int(s) * 1.4))

Теперь будет округлять в ближайшую сторону.

@WilhelmvonHermann, вам помог этот ответ? Если да, то его стоит принять — так вы покажите другим, что ответ от автора является полезным, и он решил вашу проблему
